# Can anyone (including Google) get a list of the files on the server that holds my website?

Tags: html

1. If I have an html file on a web server without any links in it and without any links pointing to it *anywhere*, will Google be able to see it? Will Google be able to promote it?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on webmasters.stackechange.com

Comment: have a look at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/21500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, probably.

Longer answer: For the most part, search engines like Google work by following links around, not by guessing what URLs are on your server. As long as the HTML file isn't a well-known name like "index" or "home" or another value used as a default index page by web servers, then it's unlikely to be included in a search index. (disclaimer: I don't work for Google and search algorithms are proprietary, so they may actually have some URL-guessing going on)

However, if you're relying on that behavior to protect something you don't want to be seen until you're ready to promote it, your gonna have a bad time. History is full of examples of companies that decided to "hide" a URL that it wasn't ready to promote, only to be foiled by someone editing the URL string in their browser to troll for hidden content.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Google and other search engines find new pages to add to their indices by following links from one web page to another.

Some search engines, including Bing and Google, also allow webmasters to submit URLs directly, meaning that your site may get indexed even if there are no links pointing to it from the “outside world”. (Links like these are called “inbound links” in the trade.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you **really** have not links to it, the answer is NO. HTTP has no command for getting directory listing. (Well, I don't discussing the possibility of google spying via chrome browser). I you **DON'T WANT** google to see it, you can put it into a directory declared as forbidden in [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt) to be 100% sure, and make sure that you server is set up not to give a directory index. If you **WANT** google to scan it, the only way to get it is to post a link to it somewhere.